# How to filter using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

for a certain column I only want to keep the values with nan and with a value higher than 75.

my data looks as Follows:

```
55,65,80,nan,nan
```

I only want to keep `55,65,nan,nan`

I tried this, but something isn't correct with the 'or' statement:

```
df= df[(df['Unnamed: 51'].isna()) or  (df['Unnamed: 51']<=75)]
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong with the "or"?

Comment: I get this as error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Have you tried searching for this error? If I remember correctly, there are already many questions about this problem.